# Adding a new key-value to a map in Dynamo DB in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an item in a dynamodb table that has a key of type `map`. The name of the key is `mykey` and the map stored in the key is:

```
{ 
   name: something
   address: somewhere
}
```

I want to add a new item to this map data. Let's say for example, color. The updated map should look like this:

```
{ 
   name: something
   address: somewhere
   color: red
}
```

I am using JavaScript SDK but I'm unable to figure out how to go about this. After reading documentation, I think I need to use `list_append` in `updateItem` function but I am not able to figure out how.

I do not want to read data, add the new key-value, and write back. This will create a 'read before write' concurrency problem as I have multiple processes trying to update the map.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [updateItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property) API. I don't have a specific example in JavaScript, but the basic idea is this:

```
var params = {
  Key: {
    KeyName: {
      S: "KeyValue"
    }
  },
  TableName: "TheTableName",
  AttributeUpdates: {
    color: {
      Action: "ADD",
      Value: {
        S: "red"
      }
    }
  }
};

client.updateItem(params, callback);
```